# Store a video in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, video, opencv

I'm working on an algorithm which needs very fast random access to video frames in a possibly long video (minimum 30 minutes). I am currently using OpenCV's VideoCapture to read my video, but the seeking functionality is either broken or very slow. The best I found until now is using the MJPEG codec inside a MKV container, but it's not fast enough.

I can chose any video format or even create a new one. The storage space is not a problem (to some extents of course). The only requirement is to get the fastest possible seeking time to any location in the video. Ideally, I would like to be able to access to multiple frames simultaneously, taking advantages of my quad-core CPU.

I know that relational databases are very good to store large volumes of data, they allows simultaneous read accesses and they're very fast when using indexes.

Is SQLite a good fit for my specific needs ? I plan to store each video frame compressed in JPEG, and use an index on the frame number to access them quickly.

EDIT : for me a *frame* is just an image, not the entire video. A 30mn video @ 25 fps contains 30*60*25=45000 frames, and I want to be able to quickly get one of them using its number.

EDIT : For those who could be interested, I finally implemented a custom video container saving each frame in fixed-sized blocks (consequently, the position of any frame can be directly computed !). The images are compressed with the turbojpeg library and file accesses are multi-threaded (to be NCQ-friendly). The bottleneck is not the HDD anymore and I finally obtained much better perfs :)

Comment: @Cicada : there is no limit on the video size. For now I'm working on 30mn VGA video (500 MB in MPEG, 1.7GB in MJPEG), but the program is supposed to work on 5 hours video as well. What do you mean by "filesystem" ? I need to process request like "get frame no. 1530" as fast as possible. Using a database is a suggestion, if you've a better idea I'm open!

Comment: SQLite has a built-in limit of 1 GB (953 MiB) per BLOB, so each of your separate frames can't be larger than that. What I mean is, why not store frames directly as files? A database is not suited for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Cicada : Maybe I used the wrong wording (I'm not english native). For me a frame is just an image, so it won't be larger than 1MB. A 30mn video @ 25 fps contains 30*60*25 = 45000 frames. A 5h video would require 450 000 files, I don't think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think using SQLite (or any other dabatase engine) is a good solution for your problem.  A database is *not* a filesystem.

If what you need is *very fast random access*, then stick to the filesystem, it was *designed* for this kind of usage, and optimized with this in mind. As per your comment, you say a 5h video would require 450k files, well, that's not a problem in my opinion. Certainly, directory listing will be a bit long, but you will get the *absolute fastest* possible random access. And it will *certainly* be faster than SQLite because you're one level of abstraction under.

And if you're really worried about directory listing times, you just have to organize your folder structure like a tree. That will get you longer paths, but fast listing.

Comment: Sure directory listing will be very slow, but I don't care since I don't need to list those files. The tree suggestion looks interesting, but using 450k files will make the "video file" quite difficult to copy efficiently (in my experience, it's always much faster to copy a big file than a lot of small ones). Thank your for your help.

Comment: Once again, modern file systems are optimized for copying many small files (particularly EXT4), you just have to choose your tools carefully.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using NTFS, I don't know about its performances with small files but by experience when I copy thousands of files to & from my USB stick, it is very slow. Much slower than when I copy an HD movie for instance. Anyway I think I'll follow your advice and store my video in a directory-tree-based structure : it cannot be slower than what I actually use. Merci :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a high level perspective. The problem is that OpenCV isn't fast enough at seeking in the source video. This could be because

- Codecs are not OpenCV's strength
- The source video is not encoded for efficient seeking

You machine has a lot of dedicated graphics hardware to leverage, but it does not have specialized capabilities for randomly seeking within a 17 GB dataset, be it a file, a database, or a set of files. The disk will take a few milliseconds per seek. It will be better for an SSD but still not so great. Then you wait for it to load into main memory And you have to generate all that data in the first place.

Use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/developer.html), which should handle decoding very efficiently, perhaps even using the GPU. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html). (Disclaimer, I haven't used it myself.)

You might preprocess the video to add key frames. In principle this shouldn't require completely re-encoding, at least for MPEG, but I don't know much about specifics. MJPEG essentially turns all frames into keyframes, but you can find a middle ground and maybe seek 1.5x faster at a 2x size cost. But avoid hitting the disk.

---

As for SQLite, that is a fine solution to the problem of seeking within 17 GB of data. The notion that databases aren't optimized for random access is poppycock. Of course they are. A filesystem is a kind of database. Random access in 17 GB is slow because of hardware, not software.

I would recommend against using the filesystem for this task, because it's a shared resource synchronized with the rest of the machine. Also, creating half a million files (and deleting them when finished) will take a long time. That is *not* what a filesystem is specialized for. You can get around that, though, by storing several images to each file. But then you need some format to find the desired image, and then why not put them all in one file?

Indeed, (if going the 17 GB route) why not ignore the entire problem and put everything in virtual memory? VM is just as good at making the disk seek as SQLite or the filesystem. As long as the OS knows it's OK for the process to use that much memory, and you're using 64-bit pointers, it should be a fine solution, and the first thing to try.

Comment: Unfortunately, my application has some 32bit dependencies and I can't move to 64bit so the VM solution isn't appropriate. Current seeking time are ~30ms. I hope both SQLite & filesystem can beat that, even considering the hardware limitation (disk access  ~ 10ms right?)

Comment: @FrédéricTerrazzoni 30 ms is fast compared to the 40 ms refresh rate of a 25fps video, so that probably wouldn't be considered a bug in the library. Nevertheless you should try ffmpeg, it could be a lot faster. (I suppose you have the whole 500 MB video file resident initially, at least in disk cache, so that really reflects processing time.) Disk access should be ~5-8 ms, reading 40 KB at 20 MB/s would be 2 ms, and then you have JPEG decompression, which you can measure before embarking on the rewrite.

Comment: @FrédéricTerrazzoni If 30 ms the seek time *in MJPEG* using OpenCV on the 1.7 GB file, you have potentially little to gain from any of this. If you don't physically hear the disk thrashing, then the data is already in RAM. The only bottleneck is MJPEG decompression, which is exactly the same as seeking a frame (using SQLite or NTFS  or whatever) and performing JPEG decompression. In that case, you definitely need a faster decompressor.

Comment: You're right, this is not really a bug if the purpose if to play the video. In fact I didn't think about this disk access time problem when I started my app. OpenCV is more or less a wrapper around ffmpeg, so the performances should be similar. But if I obtain 8+2ms = 10ms for each image read from the disk (like you said), it'd be quite good (3x improvment!). JPEG decompression is not a problem here since the CPU is not the bottleneck, and it can be done asynchronously in another thread.

Comment: @FrédéricTerrazzoni Still… since MJPEG is just a sequence of JPEG images, I'm skeptical of the benefit of moving them into a different kind of container. Is 30 ms the figure for the the 1.7 GB MJPEG file?

Comment: Yes, and the stream is stored inside a MKV container (AVI is not better). Do you think it can be improved if I store each image contiguously into a big file (using a fixed size for each image, it is straightforward to compute the location of any frame) ? That way I'd avoid filesystem bloating, while keeping good perfs right?

Comment: @FrédéricTerrazzoni If you can get a fixed size for each image without losing quality, that sounds reasonable, but it still reinvents the index kept by a format like avi or mkv. Maybe you can use ffmpeg to build a bigger index, so it can go more directly to the desired location? Also, have you run the program through a profiler to get a good idea of where time is actually being spent?

Comment: The time is spent in the opencv dll when it seeks to another frame. I don't have the details. I think I'll use a big file and store each image contiguously. Each one will be compressed in jpeg with a padding in order to make their size equal (I don't care about loosing space). Even with a big index, ffmpeg cannot beat a direct access at frame*frameSize (don't know how the ffmpeg index is built, but it cannot be faster than that!)